# Is it possible to stop the Windows defender SERVICES?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

Local admin account | Win 10 1903

I have turned off the firewall and antivirus successfully but the services are still hanging around in the background and use CPU for a second when launching programs, etc.
I don't have permission to disable or stop them as admin and my OCD is flaring up.  I haven't found an answer to disabling the services, only turning off the antivirus/firewall.

Are they able to be disabled or are they integral to Windows and can't be?

There is also a setting in local policy that says when antivirus and antispyware are disabled, the service is stopped.  I already have the registry key to disable antispyware and the antivirus is disabled but the service is still running.  Is there another setting for antispyware somewhere?

Comment: You need to ask your IT Administrator to help you. You cannot turn off the services as a normal user. You should ask the IT Admin to help you with your issues.

Comment: Errr...did you disable it in services? https://computerstepbystep.com/windows-defender-service-windows-7.html

Comment: I am a local admin and made sure services.msc was ran as admin and I cannot disable them.  All of the options are grayed out.  I've also tried using command line options and receive access denied.

Comment: Have you tried these steps specifically: http://borncity.com/win/2017/04/19/windows-10-v-1703-how-to-disable-windows-security-center/

Comment: Yes and it is successfully disabled but the service remains running.  What point is there for the service to continue running is my point and my OCD frustration.

Comment: I always stopped the service first, then put them to Manual, or Disable the service.